# Simplifying complex nested SQL View. Transpose and versioned data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very complicated (to me, anyway) Nested SQL View.  I have several separate sub-Views that are almost all the same.  I think my view would be much more efficient if I could combine them into fewer statements.  In essence, I am trying to transpose data in a particular table, but there is also revision history in the tables.  I need to first eliminate all except the latest revision data.  I only know how to do this one at a time.  Code I've included is two of the sub-views.  I would like to combine these into one view.  I can then hopefully add in more when I understand the logic and context of the statements.

One of the Views.

The view i have actually works perfectly.  However, in certain circumstances, depending on the application calling for the SQL View, it may take several minutes to generate the results.  Mind you what I have included here is just a small portion of my entire compound View, but for sake of simplicity, I'm only posting a small part of it, that should solve 80% of the problem, if I can combine views.

```
SELECT DocumentID, VariableID, ExtensionID, Description, RevisionNo, CurrentStatusID, Date, TransitionNr, RevNr, LatestRevisionNo, Filename, Deleted
FROM     (SELECT dbo.VariableValue.DocumentID, dbo.VariableValue.VariableID, dbo.Documents.ExtensionID, dbo.VariableValue.ValueText AS PartNumber, dbo.VariableValue.RevisionNo, dbo.Documents.CurrentStatusID, 
                                    dbo.TransitionHistory.Date, dbo.TransitionHistory.TransitionNr, dbo.TransitionHistory.RevNr, dbo.Documents.LatestRevisionNo, dbo.Documents.Filename, dbo.Documents.Deleted, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
                                    dbo.VariableValue.DocumentID
                  ORDER BY dbo.VariableValue.RevisionNo DESC, dbo.TransitionHistory.TransitionNr DESC) AS Seq
FROM     dbo.Documents INNER JOIN
                  dbo.VariableValue ON dbo.Documents.DocumentID = dbo.VariableValue.DocumentID INNER JOIN
                  dbo.TransitionHistory ON dbo.Documents.DocumentID = dbo.TransitionHistory.DocumentID
WHERE  (dbo.Documents.Deleted = 0) AND (dbo.Documents.ExtensionID = 3) AND (dbo.Documents.CurrentStatusID <> 0) AND (dbo.VariableValue.VariableID = 47)) t
WHERE  Seq = 1
```

Another view (Note only difference is VariableID ="49" (AS Description) instead of "47" (AS PartNumber).

```
SELECT DocumentID, VariableID, ExtensionID, Description, RevisionNo, CurrentStatusID, Date, TransitionNr, RevNr, LatestRevisionNo, Filename, Deleted
FROM     (SELECT dbo.VariableValue.DocumentID, dbo.VariableValue.VariableID, dbo.Documents.ExtensionID, dbo.VariableValue.ValueText AS Description, dbo.VariableValue.RevisionNo, dbo.Documents.CurrentStatusID, 
                                    dbo.TransitionHistory.Date, dbo.TransitionHistory.TransitionNr, dbo.TransitionHistory.RevNr, dbo.Documents.LatestRevisionNo, dbo.Documents.Filename, dbo.Documents.Deleted, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
                                    dbo.VariableValue.DocumentID
                  ORDER BY dbo.VariableValue.RevisionNo DESC, dbo.TransitionHistory.TransitionNr DESC) AS Seq
FROM     dbo.Documents INNER JOIN
                  dbo.VariableValue ON dbo.Documents.DocumentID = dbo.VariableValue.DocumentID INNER JOIN
                  dbo.TransitionHistory ON dbo.Documents.DocumentID = dbo.TransitionHistory.DocumentID
WHERE  (dbo.Documents.Deleted = 0) AND (dbo.Documents.ExtensionID = 3) AND (dbo.Documents.CurrentStatusID <> 0) AND (dbo.VariableValue.VariableID = 49)) t
WHERE  Seq = 1
```

Any takers on this one?

Thank you.

Added 7/1/2019: 13:37pm CST

I will need to add some more detail.  No, simply adding the additional OR statement to include 47 and 49 does not work.  Mainly because 47 will end up being one column, and 49 in another.  Both had independent RevisionNo sequence to find MAX for as well.

As it stands, the entire VIEW routines that I'm using results in perfect data.  However, depending on how applications call for the VIEW, it can take in excess of 3 minutes to generate the results.  I have used In SQL Studio, When I generate results in Design mode, it only takes a few second.  I did notice that If I used any kind of TOP statement, that is where it takes up to several minutes to generate results.  Even in Studio.  I'll post some data samples.

Added 7/1/2019: 15:18pm CST

It is difficult to explain in words what I'm trying to do.  Here is a graphic of what it is I am attempting:

[Show Visual Description of this post.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIGPO.png)

Comment: This probably will boil down to a SQL tuning problem: what indexes are in place and what query plan is in use. Nevertheless, does it give you correct answers if you use `dbo.VariableValue.VariableID in (47, 49)` to get multiple entries, or if you eliminate that condition altogether and then get all records in one shot?

Comment: I added to original post.  This side works different than others i've used.

Comment: If it's taking 3 minutes, you might have full table scans in nested loops or some other thing. Could you provide some data volume estimates for these tables?

Comment: Total results for the views are just under 700 rows each.  The variablevalue table that feeds the main data is about 13,000 rows.

Comment: I added this link to my original post.  It shows graphically what I'm trying to do.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIGPO.png